# Pigeon Hole Principle: 10 balls are partitioned to 5 people, someone has sum over 11

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I have a pigeon hole principle question that I'm stuck on and would appreciate some help.

> 10 balls are labelled between 1 and 10. The balls are partitioned amongst 5 people. Prove that no matter how the balls are partitioned there will be at least one person that holds balls with values that add up to 11 or more. Use the pigeon hole principle.

I'm having trouble determining what the pigeon holes and pigeons would represent in this case.

Comment: HINT Just compute the sum of all the balls

Answer (score 2):

Just compute the sum of all the balls, which is $55$: so you have $55$ 'pigeons', and if for each of the $5$ persons the value of the balls they get can add up to at most $10$ points, then there would only be $50$ 'pigeonholes'.

So the pigeons and pigeonholes are the values or points on the balls, rather than the balls or the persons themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the balls are the pigeons and the people are the pigeon holes.

You now have $55$ pigeons for $5$ pigeon holes, which means that at least one hole will have more than $10$ pigeons.